# Is it possible to achieve rolling directory like rolling log?

Tags: java

I have a application which writes xml files to a folder. I would like to reset the Folder name every midnight. For example, lets assume xml will be written on "C:/FolderName/".

```
1st Day(Inside C:/):
FolderName

2nd Day:
FolderName
FolderName_previousdaydate
```

I should be able to find the previous day xml files inside "FolderName_previousdaydate" and current day xml files files should be available inside "FolderName".

Answer (score 1):

With Logback you can specify it in the `fileNamePattern` element of the `rollingPolicy` policy.

From the [official documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpFileNamePattern) :

> The date-and-time pattern, as found within the accolades of %d{}
>   follow java.text.SimpleDateFormat conventions. The forward slash '/'
>   or backward slash '\' characters anywhere within the fileNamePattern
>   property or within the date-and-time pattern will be interpreted as
>   directory separators.

With this code you specify to archive in a folder each log file by day with a history max of 30 days:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>C://Folder/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/file.log</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
```